Facing issue using npm install but yarn install is working fine

PS G:\React Native\IGram> npm install
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! While resolving: react-native-otp-textinput@1.1.5
npm ERR! Found: react-native@0.73.7
npm ERR! node_modules/react-native
npm ERR!   react-native@"^0.73.7" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer react-native@"*" from react-native-flash-message@0.4.2
npm ERR!   node_modules/react-native-flash-message
npm ERR!     react-native-flash-message@"^0.4.2" from the root project
npm ERR!   15 more (react-native-iphone-screen-helper, ...)
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react-native@"^0.72.4" from react-native-otp-textinput@1.1.5
npm ERR! node_modules/react-native-otp-textinput
npm ERR!   react-native-otp-textinput@"^1.1.5" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: react-native@0.72.14
npm ERR! node_modules/react-native
npm ERR!   peer react-native@"^0.72.4" from react-native-otp-textinput@1.1.5
npm ERR!   node_modules/react-native-otp-textinput
npm ERR!     react-native-otp-textinput@"^1.1.5" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\Users\tejpr\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\tejpr\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2024-05-06T06_05_02_340Z-debug-0.log

try "npm install --force". This will force the installation of the node packages under node_modules.

here Robert is correct or you can install it like 'npm install --legacy-peer-deps'.
